# How to join text in google sheets if it starts with ...?

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to join cells with text if it starts with "substitute".

Now I know joining the text without a condition creates this formula:

```
=JOIN(" ";F9:AE9)
```

However on the y-axis on this row are 3 different kinds of cells; y, n, substitute (time). It means yes, no or substitute with a specific time like; substitute (16.30-17.30). I would like the result that everything is in one cell like; Substitute (16.30-17.30) Substitute (17.00-18.00) etc. So without the n's and y's.

I thought it would be:

```
=IF(F9:AE9="^substitute";JOIN(" ";F9:AE9))
```

Or

```
=JOIN(" ";F9:AE9;IF(F9:AE9="^Substitute"))
```

However this does not work.

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/447561/how-to-use-the-and-and-or-functions-in-google-sheets/ You also have too many = signs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we have data in **A1** through **A10** and we want to `JOIN()` only those values beginning with the text *substitute*.

We can first filter the data and join the results of the filter:

```
=join(" ",filter(A1:A10,left(A1:A10,10)="substitute"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Gary!